# Send reminder at specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models class and student in rails. I have to send a reminder to all the students in a class just before 1 hr when class is going to start.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a cron job which checks all the class starting in one hour periodically and for all such classes, send reminders to all the students.

For cron job, you n consider whenever gem.

If you are planning to use sidekiq then sidekiq-scheduler is also good option.

Comment: I am begginer, can you please tell me from where I can learn that